# Calculating number of possible matrices using finite number of elements

Tags: matrices, combinations

I am new to StackExchange so forgive me if I have asked this wrongly.

I'd like to know if my working for this is correct. I am trying to calculate the total number of possible $3\times 3$ matrices with elements ranging from $0$ to $9$. My thinking is that this would be simply $10^9$ as there are $10$ possible elements and $9$ places in the $3\times 3$ matrix. The same goes for $2\times 2$ matrices, where the total number of possibilities would be $10^4$. I'd like to know if this is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,via simple permutation it can be proved that required 3x3 matrices are $10^9$ (Provided no repetition constraints are there)